# Is inserting elements into specific indices from different threads safe using an ArrayList?

Tags: java, multithreading

I don't see a problem in multiple threads adding items to specific indices in an ArrayList. Assume that the list will not be resized. There are no race conditions here. Is this assumption wrong?

Comment: By "adding items" if you mean "setting values at indexes", and if each thread deals with its own index, then it is safe.

Comment: Yes I am setting values at specific indices.

Comment: If each thread can only read and write its own indices, what is the purpose of sharing the List across threads?

Comment: Basically I want to complete some work in different threads and send all those results (stored in specific parts of a list). I am really computing some numbers per "time window" (like march april june etc.) and want a sequential way of sending back that data

Answer (score 0):

you need to make the ArrayList Thread Safe.

```
Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<YourClassNameHere>())
```

this can create a thread safe ArrayList Object.

Note: Thread Safe means that the same data can be accessed from different Thread/Processes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each thread is only allotted one index then each thread would not necessarily see updates to any of the other indices in the array because there is no [happens-before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) relationship between another thread's write and the current threads read of the indices. There are some [types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceArray.html) that do offer safety for these kinds of operations.